# Unable to create Subversion repository with compiled binaries(version 1.10.2) on AiX 7.2 machine

Tags: svn, aix

We have compiled subversion 1.10.2 on AiX machine using the compile command :-

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/temp1110/subversion/zlib" --without-berkeley-db --with-apr=/temp1110/subversion/apr --with-apr-util=/temp1110/subversion/apr-util --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal --disable-nls
```

Whereas, after generating the required files using "make" command. We are unable to create a repository. After passing the command `./svnadmin create /temp1110/home/Repo_test"`, we get the error:

> svnadmin: E000009: Can't write '/temp1110/home/Repo_test/db/current'
>   atomically svnadmin: E000009: Can't flush file
>   '/temp1110/home/Repo_test/db' to disk: Bad file number

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot solve this, this is a bug in subversion.

Or rather an AIX-specific problem: `fsync(2)` called on a directory returns `errno=EBADF` which makes `subverions/libsvn_subr/io.c:svn_io_flush_to_disk` sad.

This can be fixed with the following patch:

```
--- subversion/libsvn_subr/io.cold  2018-01-19 05:00:11.000000000 +0100
+++ subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c     2018-12-22 20:25:42.000000000 +0100
@@ -4286,7 +4286,13 @@
      return svn_error_wrap_apr(status, _("Can't move '%s' to '%s'"),
                                svn_dirent_local_style(from_path, pool),
                                svn_dirent_local_style(to_path, pool));
- 
+ #if !defined(_AIX)
+     /* on Aix, you cannot do fsync(2) on a directory,
+        also you cannot open a file for APR_WRITE
+        if its access bits are 444
+        Nonetheless this is a very useful peace of code,
+        just not for AIX.
+     */
  #if defined(SVN_ON_POSIX)
    if (flush_to_disk)
      {
@@ -4314,7 +4320,7 @@
        SVN_ERR(svn_io_file_close(file, pool));
      }
  #endif
- 
+ #endif
    return SVN_NO_ERROR;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the fix provided. We were able to compile subversion after adding this fix. Generated binaries work fine in the folder where I have compiled, where as if I move the binaries to a different location. I still get the same error :- svnadmin: E000009: Can't write '/temp1110/home/Repo_test/db/current' atomically svnadmin: E000009: Can't flush file '/temp1110/home/Repo_test/db' to disk: Bad file number. What I have noticed is generated ".la" files has the path hardcoded of the folder where I have compiled it.

Comment: @Prannoy Sounds like an unsuccessfull/incomplete install and/or PATH/LIBPATH problem. (I've written some random thougths regarding AIX, you might want to read: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html )