# Throws error while creating repository after successfully compilation of subversion source code

Tags: svn, aix

I am trying to compile the subversion 1.11.1 source code.
successfully done `./configure`

and make of subversion.
when i try to create repository using `./svnadmin` create 
it throws the error:-

```
svnadmin: E000009: Can't write '/home/lroot/svndir/db/current' atomically
svnadmin: E000009: Can't flush file '/home/lroot/svndir/db' to disk: Bad file number.
```

Does anyone have any idea about the error?

Comment: Possible duplication of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882162/unable-to-create-subversion-repository-with-compiled-binariesversion-1-10-2-on/53886432

Comment: Are you trying to create a repository on a temporary mount point?

Comment: Why do not install `svn` from AIX toolbox repo?

Comment: @RomeoNinov there is a specific need to compile the Subversion source code, hence I am trying to compile on my own rather than installing it from AIX toolbox.

Comment: @bahrep No, I am not trying to create a repository on a temporary mount point

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond i had already tried that solution which you had referred, but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: That's because the compilation/installation was not successfull, so you run the old binary again.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond do you have any link which give step by step procedure to follow for building binaries of subversion?
Or if you had compiled then can you please share/provide the exact commands to build up subversion?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the step-by-step instuctions

1. backup .../subversion-1.11.1/subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c
2. in this io.c file delete lines 4296-4322
3. cd .../subversion-1.11.1; make distclean
4. repeat the build process

Comment: build the subversion using above steps successfully and even ./svnadmin create <reposPath> is creating repository. But when I copy all those binaries to different location, and run this command ./svnadmin create <reposPath>, it throws me some error:- Symbol resolution failed for /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.a(libsvn_subr-1.so.0) because: Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXI_libexpat_so (number 9) is not exported from dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libexpat.a(libexpat.so.0). Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXD_libexpat_so (number 10) is not exported from dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libexpat.a(libexpat.so.0).

Comment: You don't have to copy binaries and libraries to different locations, there are standard places to put them: `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` (or `/usr/local/lib64`). Also please read this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0007